# pytorch - Where is “conv1d” implemented?

Tags: pytorch

I wanted to see how the conv1d module is implemented
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/conv.html#Conv1d. So I looked at functional.py but still couldn’t find the looping and cross-correlation computation.

Then I searched Github by keyword ‘conv1d’, checked conv.cpp https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/eb5d28ecefb9d78d4fff5fac099e70e5eb3fbe2e/torch/csrc/api/src/nn/modules/conv.cpp 1 but still couldn’t locate where the computation is happening.

My question is two-fold.

1. Where is the source code that "conv1d” is implemented?
2. In general, if I want to check how the modules are implemented, where is the best place to find? Any pointer to the documentation will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. It depends on the backend (GPU, CPU, distributed etc) but in the most interesting case of GPU it's pulled from [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) which is released in binary format and thus you can't inspect its source code. It's a similar story for CPU [MKLDNN](https://github.com/intel/mkl-dnn). I am not aware of any place where PyTorch would "handroll" it's own convolution kernels, but I may be wrong. *EDIT*: indeed, I was wrong as pointed out in an answer below.
2. It's difficult without knowing how PyTorch is structured. A lot of code is actually being autogenerated based on various markup files, as explained [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/1b93cb7631bf084ffb68c86992e98931634b59b7/aten/src/ATen/native/README.md). Figuring this out requires a lot of jumping around. For instance, the `conv.cpp` file you're linking [uses](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/eb5d28ecefb9d78d4fff5fac099e70e5eb3fbe2e/torch/csrc/api/src/nn/modules/conv.cpp#L83) `torch::conv1d`, which is defined [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/517c7c98610402e2746586c78987c64c28e024aa/aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp#L225) and uses [`at::convolution`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/517c7c98610402e2746586c78987c64c28e024aa/aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp#L228) which in turn uses [`at::_convolution`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/517c7c98610402e2746586c78987c64c28e024aa/aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp#L272), which dispatches to multiple variants, for instance [`at::cudnn_convolution`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/517c7c98610402e2746586c78987c64c28e024aa/aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp#L352). `at::cudnn_convolution` is, I believe, created [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b7bc49ad703faf3ea92aaef804351126e63158da/aten/src/ATen/native/native_functions.yaml#L494) via a markup file and just plugs in directly to `cuDNN` implementation (though I cannot pinpoint the exact point in code when that happens).

Answer (score 2):

Below is an answer that I got from [pytorch discussion board](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/where-is-conv1d-implemented/33050/3):

I believe the “handroll”-ed convolution is defined here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/THNN/generic/SpatialConvolutionMM.c 3

The NN module implementations are here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/aten/src
The GPU version is in THCUNN and the CPU version in THNN