# How PyTorch implements Convolution Backward?

Tags: pytorch, convolution

I read about the Pytorch's source code, and I find it's weird that it doesn't implement the `convolution_backward` function, The only [`convolution_backward_overrideable`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0cba3e3704a91bd2e0548fbec2dafccb54324194/aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp#L888-L897) function is directly raises an error and supposed not to fall here.

So I referred to CuDNN / MKLDNN implementation, they both implements functions like [`cudnn_convolution_backward`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7a0f0d24d07e4baaea64bc685b00b5918db90be5/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/Conv.cpp#L39-L44).

I got the following question:

1. What are the native implementation of CUDA/ CPU? I can find something like `thnn_conv2d_backward_out`, but I could not find where are this is called.
2. Why PyTorch didn't put the `convolution_backward` function in [Convolution.cpp](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp)? It offers an `_convolution_double_backward()` function. But this is the double backward, it's the gradient of gradient. Why don't they offer a single backward function?
3. If I want to call the native convolution/ convolution_backward function for my pure cpu/cuda tensor, how should I write code? Or where could I refer to? I couldn't find example for this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Implementation may differ depending on which backend you use, it may use CUDA convolution implementation from some library, CPU convolution implementation from some other library, or custom implementation, see here: [pytorch - Where is “conv1d” implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927358/pytorch-where-is-conv1d-implemented).

2- I am not sure about the current version, but single backward was calculated via autograd, that is why there was not an explicit different function for it. I don't know the underlying details of autograd but you can check https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/autograd/autograd.cpp. That double_backward function is only there if you need higher order derivatives.

3- If you want to do this in C, the file you linked (convolution.cpp) shows you how to do this (function at::Tensor _convolution...). If you inspect the function you see it just checks which implementation to use (params.use_something...) and use it. If you want to do this in python you should start tracing from conv until where this file convolution.cpp is called.

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to use the `grad_input`. `grad_weight` and `grad_bias` that should be calculated by the `**_convolution_backward()` function. How should I get exactly these three from the Native implementation? I mean, I know cudnn got a `cudnn_convolution_backward()`, but what about CPU/CUDA?

Comment: @Sut cudnn is a deep learning library written with cuda (it literally means CUDA Deep Neural Network), for CPU you can use mkldnn, https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b38d505e425fb32f95b7f6dbf79be93417624431/aten/src/ATen/native/mkldnn/Conv.cpp . You can check others at ATen -> Native in the repository.

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete statement. I mean, for example, when doing convolution, it will fall in `_convolution()`, this function will make judgement about using cudnn/mkldnn, if all the above doesn't work, it will fall to `at::convolution_overrideable`. I also want to refer about backward function as the `_convolution()` did, but where is the entry point of `cudnn_convolution_backward()` ? When will the `cudnn_convolution_backward_overrideable()` and other backward function be called?

Comment: @Sut As I said in my 2nd point, there is no entry point for backwards because it is not called directly, it is calculated via autograd. If you want to learn how mapping is performed, you need to look into details of how computation graph is calculated. Unfortunately I don't know the details but each Tensor (Variable to be more precise) object should hold information about what functions it involved in, and when you start backpropogation in a graph their respective backwards functions are called. Maybe start looking from grad_fn in autograd/variable.h or derivatives.yaml in tools/autograd.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured something addition to @unlut's post.

1. The convolution method are in separate files for  different implementations. You may find cudnn_convoluton_backward or mkldnn_convolution_backward easily. One tricky thing is that the final native fall function is hard to find. It is because currently Pytorch Teams are porting Thnn function to ATen, you could refer to [PR24507](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24507).

The native function could be find as [thnn_con2d_backward](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/6c5a1c50bf59ad917f82d4a4861243d3b2069fe1/aten/src/ATen/cuda/LegacyTHFunctionsCUDA.cpp#L3546-L3611).

2. The convolution backward is not calculated via autograd, rather, there must a conv_backward function and this must be recorded in derivatives.yaml. If you want to find specific backward function, refer to that file is a good start.
3. About this code, if you want to directly call thnn_backward function, you need to explicitly construct finput and fgrad_input. These are two empty tensor offering as a buffer.

```
at::Tensor finput = at::empty({0},input.options()); 
at::Tensor fgrad_input = at::empty({0}, input.options());
auto kernel_size = weight.sizes().slice(2);
auto &&result = at::thnn_conv2d_backward(grad_output, input, weight,kernel_size , stride, padding, 
finput, fgrad_input, output_mask);
```